# Creating a Reason package with a different namespace name than the NPM package

Tags: reason, bucklescript, bsconfig

I started creating a native Reason unit test library, inspired by RSpec (I did one for F# previously)

I wanted to call the library `Respect`, but since there was already an npm package named "respect", I named the npm library "re-respect". But my `bsconfig.json` specifies the package name as `respect`

```
{
  "name": "Respect",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "namespace": true,
  "sources": [
    {"dir": "src"},
    {
      "dir": "tests",
      "type": "dev"
    }
  ],
  "bs-dependencies" : [
      // add your bs-dependencies here 
  ]
}
```

I pushed the package, and imported it from a test project, where I reference the `Respect` namespace. I have this reason source file in the project:

```
open Respect.Dsl;

describe "Foo" [
  it "has a test" (fun _ => ())
] |> register;

!rootContext |> run;
```

Building the code with `npm run build` works fine, but when I run the tests, I get the error:

```
module.js:529
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'Respect/lib/js/src/dsl.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:527:15)
    ...
```

The error is clear - the npm package is installed in `node_modules/re-respect` not `node_modules/Respect` where it tries to find the code.

Am I trying to do something I shouldn't? Should my root namespace follow the NPM package name? Do I need to find a new name?

p.s. as I'm writing this, I'm realizing that there is a difference between the version no in package.json and bsconfig.json - but I doubt that is the source of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend the following:

- Turn off namespacing for your project
- Keep the `re-respect` name for your npm library and for the `bsconfig.json` file
- Keep a file `Respect.re` as the main module of your project. It will be exposed publicly as the `Respect` module and users can access it as the main module

The key takeaway here is that you don't always need namespacing, especially if your project naturally fits under a single main module.

Edit: for your `Dsl` nested module you may want to keep it inside the `Respect.re` file as a syntactically nested module:

```
/* Respect.re */
module Dsl = {
  ...
};
```

Or you may want to keep it in its own file, that's fine, you'll just need to do a little more legwork in that case, by making sure you namespace and then alias it manually:

```
/* Respect_dsl.re */
...

/* Respect.re */
module Dsl = Respect_dsl;

...
```

Then users will be able to access it just as before as `Respect.Dsl`.